# Update/Insert Large table records based on another Table ReferenceID.

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, database-trigger

I have an Internal Inventory system with the below 3 tables as

a. Stocks - Daily updated from a CSV file.

```
---------------------------------
| id | MODELNO | Discount | MRP |
---------------------------------
| 1  | MODEL_1 | 40%      | 900 |
| 2  | MODEL_A | 20%      | 600 |
---------------------------------
```

Everyday this table is truncated and new stocks data are imported from a CSV file of a merchant.(around 6 Million records)

b. Cloths Master - The master clothes database

```
----------------------------------------
| ref_id | MODELNO | Name        | MRP |
----------------------------------------
| 80      | MODEL_1 |Some Dress   | 900 |
| 81      | MODEL_A |Another Dress| 600 |
----------------------------------------
```

The `MODELNO` is unique and `ref_id` the primary key. This table is part of the internal Inventory application (Has around 4.5 Million records)

c. Inventory table - It's part of the internal Applications

```
-------------------------------------------------
| id | ref_id  | Name        | MRP | status      |
-------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 80      |Some Dress   | 900 |   ACTIVE    |
| 2  | 81      |Another Dress| 600 |   INACTIVE  |
--------------------------------------------------
```

This table stores the available inventory for the product, based on the stocks and if the discount if above 40% the product is `ACTIVE` else by default `INACTIVE`.

The required functionality is that every day I need to run a script that would loop throught stock table records, and for the `MODELNO` update the stock on the Inventory table and If the record in Inventory table does not exist then it needs to be added.

What I have tried till now is a PHP script that would.
a. Firstly, set status in Inventory table for all records to INACTIVE.
b. And for each of the records in the stocks table, check if the MODELNO exists in Cloths Master table.
b. If the records exists then get the ref_id, and check if the ref_id exists in the Inventory Table and Update/Insert record accordingly.

The problem is that the script takes more than 8+ Hrs to complete.

Can you a suggest an efficient way, that can be used to implement the above functionality.

Note :
All the inserts and updated to the Inventory table are done using CodeIgniter's batch insert/update function.
I set all the status to INACTIVE, as there may be few products that are not present in the Stock DB.

Comment: Tip: Don't store '%'.

Comment: Will do that, btw I have used Mysql Load Inline to dump the CSV file to DB. Also have added index for MODELNO, and ref_id field

Answer (score 0):

The question in this case which comes in mind is - why not using a trigger ?

Create a table so_stocks

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `so_stocks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `MODELNO` varchar(50) COLLATE uft8_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Discount` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
  `MRP` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=uft8_general_ci;

INSERT INTO `so_stocks` (`id`, `MODELNO`, `Discount`, `MRP`) VALUES
    (1, 'MODEL_1', 40, 900),
    (2, 'MODEL_A', 20, 600);
```

Create a table so_inventory

```
CREATE TABLE `so_inventory` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ref_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `Name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'uft8_general_ci',
    `MRP` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `status` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='uft8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=1
;
```

And finally a table so_cloths

```
CREATE TABLE `so_cloths` (
    `ref_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `MODELNO` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'uft8_general_ci',
    `Name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'uft8_general_ci',
    `MRP` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`ref_id`)
)
COLLATE='uft8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=1
;
```

And now the trigger

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`::1` TRIGGER `so_cloths_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `so_cloths` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO so_inventory (ref_id,Name,MRP,status)
    select sc.ref_id,sc.Name, sc.MRP, if (ss.Discount >= 40, 1,0) AS active from so_cloths AS sc
    LEFT JOIN so_stocks AS ss ON (sc.MODELNO = ss.MODELNO)
    WHERE sc.ref_id = new.ref_id;
END
```

Everytime you insert something into so_cloths an insert would be made into so_inventory.

Obviously it depends whether you want to insert data after inserting it into so_stocks or into so_cloths - you've to decide it - but the example should give you some insight.

The definer in the trigger statement has to be changed to your settings

Comment: Thank you, will give a try and get back, meanwhile, won't trigger slow down the inserts?

Comment: of course - but they are definitely faster than a php query